Visual Studio Code - intellisense issue
Just started with Arduino Community Edition for Visual Studio code. I can select the com-port, Arduino model, build and upload the code  all is working fine.
I have a intellisense problem I am not able to solve. I got errors for all my includes, e.g. my main program "LedMaster.ino"
cannot open source file "WS2812FX.h" (dependency of "LEDController.h").
I've added the full path to WS2812FX.h in my projects "c_cpp_properties.json":
"forcedInclude": [
    "C:\Users\wbk\Documents\Arduino\libraries\WS2812FX\src\WS2812FX.h"
],

This did not solve the issue. It seems that intellisense is not able to build the correct include path.
The next time I start Visual Studio Code my workspace's "c_cpp_properties.json" is rebuild and the forcedInclude added manually for "WS2812FX.h" is deleted.
How do I set up Visual Studio Code correctly?
